# Check for Visual Studio Patch (SP/KB/HF) Version in .MSI (via Wix)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

We are deploying our software via a .msi package that is created using Wix and the functionality/software deployed requires a certain (>=) patch level of Visual Studio (at this particular stage everything with the latest, cumulative update 3 / KB2662296 is our target version).

Is there any (Wix built-in) way to check whether VS(2010) has a certain patch level?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not among [these predefined properties](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixvsextension.htm), you'll have to perform registry search to find it out, save to the property and use it in your conditions.